# Taking over the Windows Run command on 'File not found'

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

When you hit the `WIN+R` (Run command) in windows, you get the Run Box:

[image]

How can I get a handle to this command incase an entry for what I am typing is not found?

For example, this works great when you type `cmd` or `calc`.

But when you type: `thisawesomething` and hit the return key, you are greeted with this:

[image]

What I want to do is either of these two:

1. Whenever the file, folder or resource is not found via RUN, a default program (which I specify) is fired.

OR

2. If I can have a program running in the background which listens to an event raised by Windows when it can't find a file, what event am I looking for?

Is this even possible?
I have tried searching for this quite a bit but have hit a wall. Any help or a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Note:
[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2734/Using-the-Windows-RunFile-dialog-The-documented-an) mentions that if I fire the RUN command programatically, there is a way to handle the notification of which program is about to be run. However, I am looking to modify (or patch) the default Windows Run functionality and not fire this programatically from another app. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Are you trying to run your program with any and everything the user mistypes, or are you just trying to alias `someawesomething` to your application? 2) Capturing when there's a file not found would give you thousands of false positives to sort through.

Comment: The article you reference is 13 years old.  I'd be careful about its applicability to current versions of Windows.

Comment: I am looking at capturing ALL `file not found` events. I already know how to add an entry for `someawesomething` (via registry) for it to execute via the run command. But I am interested in capturing all instances when an application was not found.

Comment: @rrirower Surprisingly, it works quite well on Windows 10. I just tried it sometime ago :)